# Unable to make elasticsearch as persistent volume in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to setup Elasticsearch on Kubernetes Cluster using Helm. I can setup Elasticsearch on Kubernetes Cluster without persistence. I am using below helm chart.

```
helm install --name elasticsearch incubator/elasticsearch \
    --set master.persistence.enabled=false \
    --set data.persistence.enabled=false \
    --set image.tag=6.4.2 \
    --namespace logging
```

However, i am not able to use it with Persistence. Moreover i am confused as i am using neither cloud based storage(aws,gce) nor nfs. I am using Local VM storage. 
I added disk in my VM environment formated it under ext4. And now i am trying to use it as a persistent disk for my elasticsearch Deployment.

I tried lots of ways, not working much.
For any data if you need i would be helpful to provide. 
But kindly get a solution which will work.

I just need help..

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on your kubernetes deployment. Like for example do you have a storageclass for local storage ? Kubernetes version?

Comment: Can you provide error logs?

Comment: Thanks for guys comment. I am using kubernetes 1.13.4 Version. and to be specific any logs you guys are looking for please let me know.

Comment: Moreover i am looking for a procedure to install elasticsearch with persistence volume through HELM.. If there is any working procedure it will be really helpful for me. As i am using Local Disk for persistence volume which is why the challenge in deploying coming into picture.

Comment: hey @BishwajitSamanta if my answer was correct/helpful could you mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this chart will support local storage.

Looking at the volumeClaimTemplate [such as on the master-statefulset.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/4bde54c86c3d3c1be56e428d810b93431b122e2d/incubator/elasticsearch/templates/master-statefulset.yaml#L182) shows that it's missing key parameters for a local volume setup (such as path, nodeAffinity, volumeBindingMode) described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local). If you are using a cloud deployment, just use a cloud volume claim. If you have deployed a cluster on a on-prem or just onto your computer, then you should fork the chart and adjust the volume claims to meet the requirements for local storage.

Either way on your future posts you should include relevant logs. With kubernetes errors it's helpful to see from all parts of the stack such as: kubernetes control plane logs, object events (like the output from describing the volume claim), helm logs, elasticsearch pod logs failing to discover a volume, etc etc.